# How to do 2D Random Platform Spawner without colliding on top of each other?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am creating a simple 2D platform game where the player will be jumping upwards in an infinite mode. Something like Doodle Jump! I am currently trying to make a breakable platform and a normal one but I have been having some problems spawning 2 different platforms at once. I did this code below and it seems to have 2 of the platforms colliding on top of each other

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlatformSpawner : MonoBehaviour{

    [SerializeField]
    GameObject PlatformPrefab;

    public float radius = 0f;

    [SerializeField]
    GameObject PlayerPrefab;

    [SerializeField]
    CameraFollow cameraScript;

    [SerializeField]
    GameManager gameManagerScript;

    BoxCollider2D playerBoxCol2d;

    public float topPlatformYPos = 0;


    void Start(){

        SpawnPlatformStart();
        SpawnBreakPlatformStart();

    }

/*This is the Platform Spawner when start */


    void SpawnPlatformStart(){

        float yPos = -4f;
        float xPos = 0f;

        GameObject playerGo = Instantiate (PlayerPrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

        playerBoxCol2d = playerGo.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D> ();

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

            xPos = Random.Range (-2f, 2f);
            GameObject platformGo = Instantiate (PlatformPrefab, new Vector3 (xPos, yPos, 0f), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

            cameraScript.player = playerGo.transform;

            if (i <= 0) {

                playerGo.transform.position = new Vector3 (xPos, yPos + 1f, 0f);

            }

            Platform platformScript = platformGo.GetComponent<Platform> ();
            GetComponentForPlatformScript (platformScript);

            topPlatformYPos = yPos;
            yPos += 2f;

        }
    }

/*This is the different Platform to spawn */

 void SpawnBreakPlatformStart(){

        float yPos = -20f;
        float xPos = f;

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

                xPos = Random.Range (6f, -3f);
                GameObject platformGo = Instantiate (BreakPlatformPrefab, new Vector3 (xPos, yPos, 0f), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;


                Platform platformScript = platformGo.GetComponent<Platform> ();

                GetComponentForPlatformScript (platformScript);

                topPlatformYPos = yPos;
                yPos += 4f;

        }
    }

        void GetComponentForPlatformScript(Platform _platformScript){

            _platformScript.playerBoxCollider2d = playerBoxCol2d;
            _platformScript.PlatformSpawnerScript = this;
            _platformScript.cameraTrans = cameraScript.gameObject.transform;

}

    void GetComponentForPlayerScript(PlayerController _playerScript){
        _playerScript.cameraTrans = cameraScript.gameObject.transform;
        _playerScript.gameManagerScript = this.gameManagerScript;

    }

}
```

Comment: Please explain the scope of your question, explain your problem and ask a specific question. ([How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) Also, format your code correctly (select all and press Ctrl+K).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Sorry! I am quite confused with this site and I am fairly new here. Thank you for your advise!